# Javascript replace and regexp syntax issue

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

Hello everybody I was trying to replace more than one string in an exercise for myself but I'm stucking with a regexp...
Since It's impossible to call two times `replace` I need to write a regexp to achieve my goal and I'm a noob with Regexp.

Basically I would like to write `trace("Hello World");` and replace / remove `trace("`at start and `");"`  at the end of my String.

If I could use `replace` two times in a function it could be write as following statement :

```
<input type="text" id="input" onKeyUp="update()">
<p id="output"></p>
```

The script could be look like this:

```
    function update(){
            var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
            if (x.startsWith("trace(\"") && x.endsWith("\");")){
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x.replace('trace(\"', '');
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x.replace('\");', '');
            }else{
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
            }
        }
```

So till now my output is `trace("Hello World` or `Hello World");`if I comment the second `replace` statement.

The output should be Hello World with a correct Regexp I suppose.

Any help will be appreciate!
And sorry for my poor English.
Best regards.
Nicolas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the below answer is suitable for you.

**x=x.replace('trace("', '');**

```js
   function update(){
            var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
            if (x.startsWith("trace(\"") && x.endsWith("\");")){
              x=x.replace('trace(\"', '');
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x.replace('\");', '');
            }else{
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
            }
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onKeyUp="update()">
<p id="output"></p>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I tough that I needed a regex to reach my goal. If someone have an idea to realize this with a regex, feel free to answer just to satisfy my curiosity. ;)

Comment: Your answer is short, clear and efficient logesh sankar!